# What is in a bootable disk and how it is different from an ISO file?

Tags: boot, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I want to install "Console OS" (an Android OS for the PC) on a virtual machine, but the download is not an iso file and I don't know what to do now. The download has this "Win32DiskImager.exe" file that made my USB drive 500 MB instead of 14 GB but I still don't know what to do with it.

How is what I have in my USB drive currently different from an iso file?

Can I convert it into a .iso?

I just want to use this OS in a VM (I am using Oracle's VM software).

Comment: what is the download if not an .iso? Win32DiskImager is a utility for working with image formats, and is not directly related to your OS download. Please clarify on what the download actually consists of.

Answer (score 1):

The disk imager executable wrote a bootable disk image to your USB drive. Think of it like a bootable CD or DVD. If you select to boot from the USB, it will load the installer or live OS from the USB in a similar fashion.

You could try following [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/) tutorial to attempt booting from the USB.

Comment: You forgot the link for "this tutorial".

Comment: No, I didn't. Hover over the blue "this" text.